# Error while iterating over an ArrayList inside HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a HashMap implemented as:

```
Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> hm = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

After the following operations:

```
hm.put((Integer) 1, new ArrayList<Integer>());
hm.put((Integer) 2, new ArrayList<Integer>());
(hm.get(1)).add(2);
(hm.get(1)).add(2);
(hm.get(1)).add(3);
(hm.get(2)).add(4);
```

I get my Map as:

```
1: [2,2,3]
2: [4]
```

Now, I want to remove all the occurences of 2 from key 1, i.e., I want to modify my HashMap so that it looks like:

```
1: [3]
2: [4]
```

I did the following:

```
for(List<Integer> list : (hm.get(1)))
{
    list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(2));
}
```

However, while compilation, this error shows up:

```
error: incompatible types
        for(List<Integer> list : hm.get(1))
                                       ^
required: List<Integer>
found:    Integer
1 error
```

However, when I run:

```
System.out.println((hm.get(1)).getClass());
```

I get:

```
class java.util.ArrayList
```

According to which, I think, my code is fine (Even after applying casts, this error shows up in another form).

I don't know as to why this is happening. What am I doing wrong? How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type of variable in the `for-each` loop should be covariant with the type of the **element** stored in the *Collection* you are iterating over.

`hm.get(1)` will get you the `List<Integer>` mapped to the key `1`. Iterating over that `List<Integer>` will get you an `Integer`, whereas you are trying to store it in a `List<Integer>`. The `for-each` variable should be `Integer` and not `List<Integer>`. Even better an `int`, since `Integer` would anyways be unboxed to an `int`.

Having said that, there is no need of that loop at all. Just the following code would work:

```
hm.get(1).removeAll(Collections.singleton(2));
```

Also, there are some other important issues in your code. For example:

1. The way you are doing `put()`:

   ```
   hm.put((Integer) 1, new ArrayList<Integer>());
   ```

   is better written as:

   ```
   hm.put(1, new ArrayList<Integer>());
   ```

   `1` will be auto-boxed to `Integer` wrapper. You don't need to worry about that.
2. Also, there is no need to surround each method invocation with parenthesis, when you are chaining method calls. So,

   ```
   (hm.get(1)).add(2);
   ```

   is better written as:

   ```
   hm.get(1).add(2);
   ```
3. Thirdly, it's better to declare your map as:

   ```
   Map<Integer, List<Integer>> hm = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
   ```

   It just provides you the flexibility of adding a `LinkedList` or an `ArrayList` or any other implementation inside the map.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm new to programming, and your inputs have definitely taught me something.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to iterate through your `List<Integer>` instead of just using it directly. Skip the `for` loop and just do

```
hm.get(1).removeAll(Collections.singleton(2));
```